I cannot run ssh command inside my container
I am new to docker, I have got dockerfile as below to create docker image. Then I build the image and run the following test commands:
docker run --rm --network host -d -v .:/ansible ansible:latest tail -f /dev/null
docker exec -it c0a5f9c07635 ansible --version
docker exec -it c0a5f9c07635 ansible-playbook test.yaml
docker exec -it c0a5f9c07635 bash

ansible command works fine. However, when I get in to the bash, I cannot run ssh command:
root@docker-desktop:/ansible# ssh 8.8.8.8
bash: ssh: command not found

Did I miss anything?
FROM ubuntu:22.04
WORKDIR /ansible
COPY requirements.txt /ansible
RUN apt update && apt install -y gcc python3 \
    python3-pip \
    iputils-ping \
    openssh-client

RUN apt-get clean all
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip; \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt


Try docker build -t ansible:latest --no-cache . to make sure you have an updated image.

Your container isn't doing anything, and it doesn't seem like you need a container just to make an outbound ssh connection.  Can you just run this ssh command from the host?

@david maze, this is just my first step. The plan is to build ansible docker container, I will update my ansible inventory locally in my host, container will mount the local inventory folder and execute playbook. And I can share this container with others so they can have the same working environment.

Container does need outbound ssh connection to login to remote devices to perform ansible playbook operations.

try without USER 0 and some minors for readability
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /ansible
ENV ANSIBLE_VERSION 2.9.17

RUN apt update && apt install -y gcc python3 \
    python3-pip \
    iputils-ping \
    openssh-client \
    && apt-get clean  && rm -Rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  
# ...

Maybe you could use ubuntu 22.04 and requirements.txt
FROM ubuntu:22.04

#...

## pip Alternative using requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


Thanks for the advice, I have updated my dockerfile to use ubuntu 22.04 and used requirements.txt to install ansible. However, I am getting same error when trying to ssh from the container. root@docker-desktop:/ansible# ssh 8.8.8.8 bash: ssh: command not found

did you remove USER 0 ? , check first part of dockerfile. Also delete/rebuild your docker image.

yes I did remove the USER 0 and completely delete and rebuild my image. Still the same error.

try middle section as in the answer:  RUN apt update && apt install -y gcc python3 \     python3-pip \     iputils-ping \     openssh-client  RUN apt-get clean  

ok, so I have to use "docker builder prune" and then rebuild everything, it works :)

Thanks for the help, but I am wondering why the previous dockerfil does not work?

Side note: apt-get clean should be executed in the same RUN, otherwise another layer will be created and the image size will not be reduced

When you switch users in a Dockerfile, the environment variables and path may change. You could run which ssh to verify path

added && apt-get clean  && rm -Rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  in same RUN operation
